# How to compute p value for my fitting function?

Tags: matlab, p-value

I have fitted mixture of 3 Gaussian function to my data and it is fitting pretty well. My question is how well the fitting defined numerically. Is that can be defined by p-value. If yes then how can I calculate from fitting function itself.

```
   g = fittype( @(c1,c2,p5,p6,p3,p4,p1,p2, x) (c1)*(1/(p6*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-p5).^2)./(2*(p6.^2))) + ...
   (c2)*(1/(p4*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-p3).^2)./(2*(p4.^2))) + ...
    (1-c1-c2)*(1/(p2*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-p1).^2)./(2*(p2.^2)))       );

 %xr and yr is data (basically normalized histogram) 
[fE,GE,O] = fit(xr',yr',g,'StartPoint',startingVals);

%O gives me following quantity. 
        numobs: 50
         numparam: 8
    residuals: [50×1 double]
     Jacobian: [50×8 double]
     exitflag: 3
firstorderopt: 7.763960157882235e-04
   iterations: 24
    funcCount: 225
 cgiterations: 0
    algorithm: 'trust-region-reflective'
     stepsize: 0.002272922321389
      message: 'Success, but fitting stopped because change in residual…'
```

There is no p-value here. How to compute that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `corrcoef` function see [matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html).

Basically, if you have your data `y`, and the predicted data from your fitted function `Y`, you just do :

```
[R,p] = corrcoef(y, Y);
```

Which will give you the R value, and the p value of the correlation between you data and your predicted data after the gaussian fit, so basically how well you fit is working.

`y` and `Y` must correspond to the same input value:

Let's say that `f` is the "function" of your data. It verifies 
`y = f(x)`, (for each value of `x` you have a measurment `y`).

Then you must have `Y = f_fitted(x)`, with `f_fitted` being the gaussian function resulting from you fit.